# Qt designer assign a wrong margin when using a Custom QTabWidget

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer, pyqt6

I'm facing a strange problem while using Qt designer (I use pyqt6) :

In my project, I have created a custom TabWidget (that allows the user to drag and drop a tab to create new windows). Then, I have promoted the initial QTabWidget to the custom one in Qt designer so the generated code directly uses my class, which prevent me from modifying the code afterwards (for some reason modifying the code is not an option). The problem is that when I generate the code with the custom tab bar, designer set the margin layout to zero in each tabs, instead of letting its default value, with the following line :

```
self.gridLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I do not have modified the margin layout (which by default is set to 9), and I want it to be precisely 9 (or at least not zero). If I use the standard QTabWidget, this line does not appear in my code, and therefore the margin is still set to 9.

Any idea about why this strange behavior appears ?

Here is the content of the .ui file created using qt designer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>648</width>
    <height>354</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="1">
    <widget class="DetachableTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
     <property name="currentIndex">
      <number>1</number>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
      <attribute name="title">
       <string>Tab 1</string>
      </attribute>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
      <attribute name="title">
       <string>Tab 2</string>
      </attribute>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
         <property name="plainText">
          <string>ezcazecazezcazecazezcazecazezcazecazezcazecaz</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>DetachableTabWidget</class>
   <extends>QTabWidget</extends>
   <header>pyufa.utils.DetachableTabWidget</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is my custom class, which in my opinion won't help a lot :

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


class DetachableTabWidget(QTabWidget):

    """
    Custom class equivalent to the QTabWidget class, implementing the possibility to drag and drop tab
    outside the tab widget, creating a new window.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tabBar = self.TabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.onDetachTabSignal.connect(self.detachTab)
        self.tabBar.onMoveTabSignal.connect(self.moveTab)

        self.setTabBar(self.tabBar)


    def setMovable(self, movable):

        """
        The default movable functionality of QTabWidget must remain disabled so as not to conflict with the added features

        :param movable: //
        """

        pass


    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def moveTab(self, fromIndex, toIndex):
        """
        Move a tab from one position (index) to another

        :param fromIndex: the original index location of the tab
        :param toIndex: the new index location of the tab
        """
        widget = self.widget(fromIndex)
        icon = self.tabIcon(fromIndex)
        text = self.tabText(fromIndex)

        self.removeTab(fromIndex)
        self.insertTab(toIndex, widget, icon, text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(toIndex)



    @pyqtSlot(int, QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):

        """
        Detach the tab by removing it's contents and placing them in a DetachedTab dialog

        :param index: the index location of the tab to be detached
        :param point: the screen position for creating the new DetachedTab dialog
        """

        # Get the tab content
        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)
        contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()

        # Create a new detached tab window
        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(contentWidget, self.parentWidget())
        detachedTab.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.NonModal)
        detachedTab.setWindowTitle(name)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setObjectName(name)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.onCloseSignal.connect(self.attachTab)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.show()


    @pyqtSlot(QWidget, type(''), QIcon)
    def attachTab(self, contentWidget, name, icon):

        """
        Re-attach the tab by removing the content from the DetachedTab dialog,
        closing it, and placing the content back into the DetachableTabWidget

        :param contentWidget: the content widget from the DetachedTab dialog
        :param name: the name of the detached tab
        :param icon: the window icon for the detached tab
        """

        # Make the content widget a child of this widget
        contentWidget.setParent(self)


        # Create an image from the given icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            tabIconPixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            tabIconImage = tabIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            tabIconImage = None


        # Create an image of the main window icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            windowIconPixmap = self.window().windowIcon().pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            windowIconImage = windowIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            windowIconImage = None


        # Determine if the given image and the main window icon are the same.
        # If they are, then do not add the icon to the tab
        print(name)
        if name  == 'Parameters':
            index = 0
        elif name  == 'Mute':
            index = 1
        elif name  == 'Status Words':
            index = 2
        elif name  == 'Data':
            index = 3

        if tabIconImage == windowIconImage:
            index = self.insertTab(index,contentWidget, name)
            # index = self.addTab(contentWidget, name)
        else:
            # index = self.addTab(contentWidget, icon, name)
            index = self.insertTab(index,contentWidget, icon, name)


        # Make this tab the current tab
        if index > -1:
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)



    class DetachedTab(QDialog):

        """
        When a tab is detached, the contents are placed into this QDialog.  The tab
        can be re-attached by closing the dialog or by double clicking on its
        window frame.
        """

        onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QWidget,type(''), QIcon)

        def __init__(self, contentWidget, parent=None):
            QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

            layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
            self.contentWidget = contentWidget
            layout.addWidget(self.contentWidget)
            self.contentWidget.show()
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.Window)


        def event(self, event):

            """ Capture a double click event on the dialog's window frame

            Disabled by default. Uncomment and remove pass instruction to enable it.

            :param event: true if the event was recognized
            """

            # If the event type is QEvent.NonClientAreaMouseButtonDblClick then
            # close the dialog

            # if event.type() == 176:
            #     event.accept()
                # self.close()

            return QDialog.event(self, event)



        def closeEvent(self, event):
            """
            If the dialog is closed, emit the onCloseSignal and give the content widget back to the DetachableTabWidget

            :param event: a close event
            """

            self.onCloseSignal.emit(self.contentWidget, self.objectName(), self.windowIcon())



    class TabBar(QTabBar):

        """ The TabBar class re-implements some of the functionality of the QTabBar widget

        """

        onDetachTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, QPoint)
        onMoveTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, int)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setElideMode(Qt.TextElideMode.ElideRight)
            self.setSelectionBehaviorOnRemove(QTabBar.SelectionBehavior.SelectLeftTab)

            self.dragStartPos = QPoint()
            self.dragDropedPos = QPoint()
            self.mouseCursor = QCursor()
            self.dragInitiated = False



        def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
            """
            Send the onDetachTabSignal when a tab is double clicked. Disabled by default.
            Uncomment and remove pass instruction to enable it.

            :param event: a mouse double click event
            """
            pass
            #event.accept()
            #self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(event.pos()), self.mouseCursor.pos())


        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            """ Set the starting position for a drag event when the mouse button is pressed

            :param event: a mouse press event
            """

            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
                self.dragStartPos = event.pos()

            self.dragDropedPos.setX(0)
            self.dragDropedPos.setY(0)

            self.dragInitiated = False

            QTabBar.mousePressEvent(self, event)



        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            """
            Determine if the current movement is a drag.  If it is, convert it into a QDrag.  If the
            drag ends inside the tab bar, emit an onMoveTabSignal.  If the drag ends outside the tab
            bar, emit an onDetachTabSignal.

            :param event: a mouse move event
            """

            # Determine if the current movement is detected as a drag
            if not self.dragStartPos.isNull() and ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPos).manhattanLength() > QApplication.startDragDistance()):
                self.dragInitiated = True

            # If the current movement is a drag initiated by the left button
            if (((event.buttons() & Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)) and self.dragInitiated):

                # Stop the move event
                finishMoveEvent = QMouseEvent(QEvent.Type.MouseMove, event.position(), Qt.MouseButton.NoButton, Qt.MouseButton.NoButton, Qt.KeyboardModifier.NoModifier)
                QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, finishMoveEvent)

                # Convert the move event into a drag
                drag = QDrag(self)
                mimeData = QMimeData()
                mimeData.setData('action', b'application/tab-detach')
                drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

                #Create the appearance of dragging the tab content
                pixmap = self.parentWidget().grab()
                targetPixmap = QPixmap(pixmap.size())
                targetPixmap.fill(QColor(0,0,0,0))
                painter = QPainter(targetPixmap)
                painter.setOpacity(0.85)
                painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
                painter.end()
                drag.setPixmap(targetPixmap)

                # Initiate the drag
                dropAction = drag.exec(Qt.DropAction.MoveAction | Qt.DropAction.CopyAction)

                # If the drag completed outside of the tab bar, detach the tab and move
                # the content to the current cursor position
                if dropAction == Qt.DropAction.IgnoreAction:
                    event.accept()
                    self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.mouseCursor.pos())

                # Else if the drag completed inside the tab bar, move the selected tab to the new position
                elif dropAction == Qt.DropAction.MoveAction:
                    if not self.dragDropedPos.isNull():
                        event.accept()
                        self.onMoveTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.tabAt(self.dragDropedPos))
            else:
                QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)


        def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
            """ Determine if the drag has entered a tab position from another tab position

            :param event: a drag enter event
            """

            mimeData = event.mimeData()
            formats = mimeData.formats()

            if 'action' in formats and mimeData.data('action') == 'application/tab-detach':
                event.acceptProposedAction()

            QTabBar.dragMoveEvent(self, event)


        def dropEvent(self, event):
            """ Get the position of the end of the drag

            :param event: a drop event
            """

            self.dragDropedPos = event.position()
            QTabBar.dropEvent(self, event)
```

Here is the code for a simple class that has been generated by qt designer (and does contains the line responsible of the problem)

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'pb.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.4.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pyufa.utils.DetachableTabWidget import DetachableTabWidget


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(648, 354)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = DetachableTabWidget(parent=Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.tab)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.tab)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(parent=self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Dialog", "Tab 1"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("Dialog", "ezcazecazezcazecazezcazecazezcazecazezcazecaz"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Dialog", "Tab 2"))
```

I have no idea about how to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to provide the original designer ui file, not the generated code.

Comment: @ekhumoro you're right, I've uploaded the content of the .ui file (can't direclty upload a file on stackoverflow).

Comment: Probably related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39910217

Comment: This is caused by another bug in pyuic. The treatment of contents-margins should be different when the parent is a container widget (such as a QTabWidget). However, pyuic fails to identify promoted widgets as containers because the relevant code uses `type` instead of `isinstance`. This is pretty annoying, because it's not possible to override the behaviour in the `__init__` of the promoted class (since the margins are set *after* the instance is created). A work-around would be to do `tab.layout().setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, -1)` after `setupUi()` has been called.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for the explanation, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was already using this work-around, but wanted to know if the origin of the problem was qt or my project. In that case, I will just use the work-around instead of trying to fix my project for no reason.